# Cannot install git on debian

Tags: git, amazon-ec2, debian

Here's my sources.list:

```
deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt precise main restricted universe multiverse
deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt precise-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt precise-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt precise-security main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://cloudfront.debian.net/debian wheezy main
deb-src http://cloudfront.debian.net/debian wheezy main
deb http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main
deb http://cloudfront.debian.net/debian wheezy-updates main
deb-src http://cloudfront.debian.net/debian wheezy-updates main
deb http://http.debian.net/debian wheezy-backports main
```

And here's the result of `apt-get install git`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  git-man less libclass-isa-perl liberror-perl libswitch-perl patch perl
  perl-modules rsync
Suggested packages:
  git-daemon-run git-daemon-sysvinit git-doc git-el git-arch git-cvs git-svn
  git-email git-gui gitk gitweb ed diffutils-doc perl-doc
  libterm-readline-gnu-perl libterm-readline-perl-perl make
  libpod-plainer-perl
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  git git-man less libclass-isa-perl liberror-perl libswitch-perl patch perl
  perl-modules rsync
0 upgraded, 10 newly installed, 0 to remove and 39 not upgraded.
Need to get 35.6 kB/16.2 MB of archives.
After this operation, 47.4 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  libswitch-perl patch
Install these packages without verification [y/N]? y
Get:1 http://cloudfront.debian.net/debian/ wheezy/main libclass-isa-perl all 0.36-3 [11.9 kB]
Get:2 http://cloudfront.debian.net/debian/ wheezy/main liberror-perl all 0.17-1 [23.8 kB]
Fetched 12.3 kB in 0s (461 kB/s)          
Failed to fetch http://cloudfront.debian.net/debian/pool/main/libc/libclass-isa-perl/libclass-isa-perl_0.36-3_all.deb  Size mismatch
Failed to fetch http://cloudfront.debian.net/debian/pool/main/libe/liberror-perl/liberror-perl_0.17-1_all.deb  Size mismatch
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

I'm an Ubuntu user, so debian is a little new to me, but they should be similar. Neither of the suggestions " maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?" do anything different.

Some help would rock!

**Update** I've getting a very similiar error trying to install mysql: 
`WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  libswitch-perl
Get:1 http://cloudfront.debian.net/debian/ wheezy/main libclass-isa-perl all 0.36-3 [11.9 kB]
Fetched 12.3 kB in 0s (862 kB/s)

Failed to fetch http://cloudfront.debian.net/debian/pool/main/libc/libclass-isa-perl/libclass-isa-perl_0.36-3_all.deb  Size mismatch
Unable to correct missing packages.`

Seems like something's messed up. I'd love some help, I'm stuck in my tracks here.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect a network error of some kind. Note that both times you are fetching "12.3 kB" rather than the package sizes.

Try looking in `/var/cache/apt/archives/partial` and see if you can view the contents of the files there with `less`. Hopefully it will show you some text that will indicate what the error is.